# reduce array of array into a flat array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm stuck at transforming a data structure:

```
let d = [
  { no: 1, score: 7000 },
  { no: 2, score: 10000 },
  [
    { no: 1, score: 8500 },
    { no: 2, score: 6500 }
  ]
];

    
d = d.reduce((accum, o) => {
   
}, [])
```

How can I produce this?

```
[{name: 'no 1', score: [7000, 8500]}, {name: 'no 2', score: [10000, 6500]}]
```

Comment: If you fix the result/syntax error it will be a dupe of: [How to group an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

Comment: @Andreas it's fixed. No it's not the same, my raw data is an array of array

Comment: It is - with an additional [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) call before the actual grouping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with simple `reduce`,

```
const result = d.flat().reduce((acc: {name: string, score: number[]}[], curr) => {
  const { no, score } = curr;
  let item = acc.find(a => a.name === `no ${no}`);
  if (!item) {
    item = { name: `no ${no}`, score: []};
    acc.push(item);
  }

  item.score.push(score);
  return acc;
    
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: the most simple solution, clean. Thanks!

Comment: @NadielyJade Be careful, the `flat` expects as parameter `depth` (1 by default). So the solution above is perfect if you know the depth of the array. If the depth is not known you will need a recursive call of reducer.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you not only need to flatten the list, but also group by `no` property.

For flatting, you can use [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). It's quite a new feature, so if you don't use polyfills, you probably can't use it. So you can check for [alternative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Alternatives) implementations.

For grouping, you can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to the object where the key is `no` property. Note, that if multiple `no` properties exist, you need to save an array of all `score` values.

Example:

```js
const d = [{ no: 1, score: 7000 },
    { no: 2, score: 10000 },
   [ { no: 1, score: 8500 },
    { no: 2, score: 6500 }]]


const grouped = d.flat().reduce((prev, cur) => {
    if (cur.no in prev) {
        prev[cur.no].score.push(cur.score)
    } else {
        prev[cur.no] = {
            name: 'no ' + cur.no,
            score: [cur.score]
        }
    }
    return prev
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(grouped))
```

> In the example we use modifications. It is possible to do it without modifications - return a new copy during each reduction iteration. However, depending on array size, there can be performance issues. Also, it's safe to do modifications, because we create a new object in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let d = [{ no: 1, score: 7000 },
    { no: 2, score: 10000 },
   [ { no: 1, score: 8500 },
    { no: 2, score: 6500 }]]
    
    const result=d.flat().reduce((acc,curr)=>{
    if(acc[curr.no]){
      acc[curr.no].score.push(curr.score)
    } else {
      const keys=Object.keys(curr)
      acc[curr.no]={ name: keys[0]+ ' '+curr.no, score:[curr.score]}
    }
    return acc;
    },{})
console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.flat()` call before the actual grouping, then use reduce function create the result.

```js
let d = [{
    no: 1,
    score: 7000
},
{
    no: 2,
    score: 10000
},
[{
        no: 1,
        score: 8500
    },
    {
        no: 2,
        score: 6500
    }
]
]

const result = d.flat().reduce((result, element) => {
const key = element.no;
if (!result[key]) {
    result[key] = {
        name: `no ${key}`,
        score: []
    }
}

result[key].score.push(element.score);
return result;
}, {})
console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sleek functional solution for typescript, since you included the tag-

```
const arr = [
    { no: 1, score: 7000 },
    { no: 2, score: 10000 },
    [
        { no: 1, score: 8500 },
        { no: 2, score: 6500 },
    ],
];

const result = Object.entries(
    arr.flat().reduce((accum: { [key: number]: number[] }, el: { no: number; score: number }) => {
        accum[el.no] = (accum[el.no] ?? []).concat(el.score);
        return accum;
    }, {})
).map(([num, scores]) => ({ no: Number(num), scores: scores }));

console.log(result);
```

Result-

```
[
  { no: 1, scores: [ 7000, 8500 ] },
  { no: 2, scores: [ 10000, 6500 ] }
]
```

This flattens the inner arrays first using [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). Then it uses `reduce` to construct an object that has the `no` values as keys and `score` values as an array of values.

In the end, the reduce results in `{ 1: [7000, 8500], 2: [10000, 6500] }` - turn that into entries using `Object.entries` to get `[['1',  [7000, 8500]], ['2', [10000, 6500]]]`

Finally, map over the entries to turn the `['1',  [7000, 8500]]` format into `{ no: 1, scores: [ 7000, 8500 ] }` format and you're done!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a dynamic approach which groups by the given key and takes all other properties for a new array.

```js
const
    groupBy = key => (r, value) => {
        if (Array.isArray(value)) return value.reduce(group, r);
        const { [key]: _, ...o } = value;
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => ((r[_] ??= { [key]: _ })[k] ??= []).push(v));
        return r;
    }
    data = [{ no: 1, score: 7000 }, { no: 2, score: 10000 }, [{ no: 1, score: 8500 }, { no: 2, score: 6500 }]],
    group = groupBy('no'),
    result = Object.values(data.reduce(group, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.flat()`

or if you have any array like,

```
let d = [
  { no: 1, score: 7000 },
  { no: 2, score: 10000 },
  [
    { no: 1, score: 8500 },
    { no: 2, score: 6500 }
  ]
];
```

**and then use `d.flat()`**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let d = [
    { no: 1, score: 7000 },
    { no: 2, score: 10000 },
    [
        { no: 1, score: 8500 },
        { no: 2, score: 6500 }
    ]
]


const reducer = (arr, start = []) => arr.reduce((acc, next) => {
    if (Array.isArray(next)) return reducer(next, acc);
    for (const value of acc) {
        if (value.name === `no ${next.no}`) {
            value.score = [...value.score, next.score];
            return acc;
        }
    }
    
    return [...acc, {
        name: `no ${next.no}`,
        score: [next.score]
    }];
}, start);

console.log(reducer(d));
```